# how do I make my dropdown menu wider?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, dropdown

I am using the archi wordpress theme which is a great theme. 
I am looking how to make the dropdown menu width wider so my text is on 1 line rather then 2 lines.

My website: http://cobbys.gentwijzer.be/fabrieksverkoop/

For example menu item: Stoffen, dropdown is ok except for "brandvertragende stoffen" . How do I increase the width of the dropdown so it will be on 1 line.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would change from:

```
#mainmenu li ul {
    width: 200px;
}
#mainmenu li li a {
    width: 200px;
}
```

to

```
#mainmenu li ul {
    width: auto;
}
#mainmenu li li a {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Using `width: auto` will allow the `ul` of the dropdown to grow as needed and you won't be stuck specifying a universal width for all dropdowns or manually setting a specific width for each dropdown.

`white-space: nowrap;` prevents the text from wrapping to a new line when there is not sufficient space to do so.

Comment: @user3613444 please accept my solution if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` of `#mainmenu li ul` to what ever you want(for example 300px) and on `#mainmenu li li a` use `width:auto`